# Properly configuring user registration using 2 forms

Tags: python, django

I am trying to submit 2 forms at a time to create my student user in Django. I have been struggling for a while now, but I think I'm finally closing to an end on how to manage 2 forms at a time for my users to register. But when I fill in the data and then click register, I get error: "This field is required." under my student ID field. What am I doing wrong ? Thanks.

```js
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(
        label='Password',
        max_length=32,
        required=True,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput,
    )

    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label='Confirm',
        max_length=32,
        required=True,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput,
        help_text="Make sure they match!",
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password', 'password2')


class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('phone', 'student_ID', 'photo')
```

```css
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass


class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    student_ID = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=14,
                                  validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^.{14}$',
                                                             message='The ID needs to be 14 characters long.')])
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='students_images')
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_student(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Student.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_student(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

```html
@csrf_protect
def student_register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form1 = UserForm(request.POST, prefix="user")
        form2 = StudentForm(request.POST, prefix="profile")
        if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            # create initial entry for user
            username = form1.cleaned_data["username"]
            password = form1.cleaned_data["password"]
            new_user = User.objects.create_user(username, password)
            new_user.save()

            # create entry for UserProfile (extension of new_user object)
            profile = form2.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = new_user
            profile.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("index")
    else:
        form1 = UserForm(prefix="user")
        form2 = StudentForm(prefix="profile")
    c = {
        'form1': form1,
        'form2': form2,
    }
    return render(request, "student_signup_form.html", c)
```

```html
 <form method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <p style="color:red"> {{ form.username.errors }}</p>
                        {{ form1.as_p }}
                        {{ form2.as_p }}
                        <input type="submit" value="Create the account">
                    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you don't need @csrf_protect if you use {% csrf_token %} in template.
Second, you are probably getting student_ID required because you are trying to create a profile in signal providing just the user.

You can change your models like this:

**models.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass


class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    student_ID = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=14,
                                  validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^.{14}$', message='The ID needs to be 14 characters long.')], null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='students_images', null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True, default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**views.py**

```
def student_register(request):
    data = dict()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form1 = UserForm(request.POST)
        form2 = StudentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            cd1 = form1.cleaned_data
            username = cd1["username"]
            password = cd1["password"]
            new_user = User.objects.create_user(username, password)
            new_user.save()
            cd2 = form2.cleaned_data
            phone = cd2['phone']
            student_ID = cd2['student_ID']
            photo = cd2['photo']
            Student.objects.create(user=new_user, phone=phone, student_ID=student_ID, photo=photo)
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        form1 = UserForm()
        form2 = StudentForm()
    data['form1'] = form1
    data['form2] = form2
    return render(request, "student_signup_form.html", data)
```

**template**

```
                <form action='' method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <p style="color:red"> {{ form.username.errors }}</p>
                    {{ form1.as_p }}
                    {{ form2.as_p }}
                    <input type="submit" value="Create the account">
                </form>
```

Comment: Perfect! Mersi!

Answer (score 0):

You can make StudentForm class a derived class of UserForm by declaring like class StudentForm(UserForm): and just submit one form that is StudentForm

It can be done like this also,

```
#models.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    student_ID = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=14,validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^.{14}$',message='The ID needs to be 14 characters long.')])
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='students_images')
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, )

User.student = property(lambda u: Student.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])

#forms.py
class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('student_ID', 'photo', 'phone', )

#views.py
def student_register(request):

    template_name = "student_signup_form.html"
    context = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':)
        form = StudentForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.student)
        if form.is_valid():
            object = request.user.student
            object.student_ID= form.cleaned_data['student_ID']
            object.photo = form.cleaned_data['photo']
            object.phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
            object.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('index')
    else:
        form = StudentForm()

    context['form'] = form
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Comment: Then how would my view function look like ? Could u show please ?